# Enable and disable link button on gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I wants to enable or disable linkbutton on some rows of gridview based on condition.. Can i enable linkbutton on one row and disable it on another row of same grid view ??my code is here

```
  protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{LinkButton lnk2 = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton2");
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd12 = new SqlCommand("Select testsession_status from student_vs_testsession_details where  testsession_id='" + v_testid.Text + "' ", con12);
        SqlDataReader dr12 = cmd12.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr12.Read())
        {
            string test_status = dr12[0].ToString();
            LinkButton lnk2 = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton2");
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (v_testtype == "Theory Test" && test_status == "Completed")
                {
                    lnk2.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    lnk2.Visible = false;
                }

            }




        }
```

Comment: What actually is your question, what is on this code not working, do you have any error message ?. To me is looks like not working, but without having it on my debugger, nether know what you logic flow of your program I can not advice you what to do. - one Bug is that you do not find the LinkButton on each line, second Bug is that you do not connect each line on gridview with each line on database.

Comment: In this case, you may need to loop through gridview control and set the link button enable/disable accordingly, because the above code will look only the current row item. not the entire rows.

 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
        {
             var link = row.FindControl("LinkButton2")
        }

Comment: how can i loop through each row and check the condition for enable/disable linkbutton ? it works without any error..but as @Deepu said the code looks only the current row itm ..

Comment: HOW can i find the LinkButton on each line, and connect each line on gridview with each line on database. ?? @Aristos  please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can easily do it in RowdataBound Event, but you have used `lnk2.Visible` property in your code.

you may be using `Visible` property for another requirement but just want to confirm you that it is used to show/hide the Linkbutton only. To enable/disble a Linkbutton, use `Enabled` property of Linkbutton. as:

```
lnk2.Enabled = true;// to enable linkbutton.
lnk2.Enabled = false;// to disable linkbutton.
```

If You want to do it using rowindex, then you can `e.Row.RowIndex` to find the current row index inside 'RowDatabound` event of gridview. as:

```
if(e.Row.RowIndex==2)
{
  LinkButton lnk2 = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton2");
  lnk2.Enabled=false;
}
```

If you want to enable/ disable Linkbutton based on value of some other column in the same row, then you can do the same inside `Rowdatabound` event. as:

```
string Namecolumnvalue = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Name"));
LinkButton lnk2 = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton2");
if(Namecolumnvalue =="Disable")
{      
  lnk2.Enabled=false;
}
else{
  lnk2.Enabled=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    --------aspx page code---------

     <asp:GridView ID="gvLibrary" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" DataKeyNames="LibMstRefNo"
                        EmptyDataText="No Client Found" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered" OnRowDataBound="gvLibrary_RowDataBound">
                        <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Issue">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                               <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkIssue" runat="server" Text="Issue" OnClick="lnkIssue_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Receive">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                               <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkReceive" runat="server" Text="Receive" OnClick="lnkReceive_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you Sure?')"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>


    ------------aspx.cs page code------------------

 protected void gvLibrary_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string nbps = e.Row.Cells[8].Text;
            if(nbps== "&nbsp;")
            {
                nbps = "";
            }
            else
            {
                nbps = e.Row.Cells[8].Text;
            }
            if (nbps == "")
            {
                LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkissue");
                LinkButton btn1 = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkReceive");
                btn.Enabled = true;
                btn1.Enabled = false;
                btn1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

            }
            else
            {
                LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkissue");
                LinkButton btn1 = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkReceive");
                btn.Enabled = false;
                btn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                btn1.Enabled = true;
            }

        }
    }
```

[image]