# concept on looping on grid view row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is a concept problem, I don't know how to solve it but hope you all can help me and understand what I mean.

I have a gridview I want to make a button visible true and false, when the quantity is larger than the remaining stock it will show the error, the value of remaining stock is beside the error message.

My gridview loop to make a button visible true and false is incorrect. Because the loop will go through all the row, first row no error message visible true, second row error visible false and it suppose can click but the third row the label error is blank and it will make the button visible true, how to solve.

**I able to create a script to detect if have word visible false or true, but how to detect the thing on template gridview?**

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in grdCart.Rows)
        {

            Response.Write("1");
            var Qty = row.FindControl("lblQty") as Label;
            var RemainQty = row.FindControl("lblremainqty") as Label;
            var errormsg = row.FindControl("lblError") as Label;

            if (Convert.ToInt32(Qty.Text) > Convert.ToInt32(RemainQty.Text))
            {
                errormsg.Text = "Stock Remain " + RemainQty.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                errormsg.Text = "";

            }
            if (errormsg.Text == null || errormsg.Text == "")//mean have
            {
                btnCheckOut.Enabled = true;
                Response.Write("2");
            }
            else
            {
                btnCheckOut.Enabled = false;
                Response.Write("3");
            }

        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
bool isError=false;
foreach (GridViewRow row in grdCart.Rows)
    {

        Response.Write("1");
        var Qty = row.FindControl("lblQty") as Label;
        var RemainQty = row.FindControl("lblremainqty") as Label;
        var errormsg = row.FindControl("lblError") as Label;

        if (Convert.ToInt32(Qty.Text) > Convert.ToInt32(RemainQty.Text))
        {
            errormsg.Text = "Stock Remain " + RemainQty.Text;
            isError = true;
            btnCheckOut.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            errormsg.Text = "";


        }

    }
if(!isError)
{
  btnCheckOut.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: woo wht is mean bool? it seen like work

Comment: its a datatype to store true or false values.
i guess you were not pulling my leg asking this :P

Answer (score 0):

Try using a ListView instead of a GridView. That'll be more flexible and you'll be able to do what you want. It requires a bit more of work, but it pays off in the end.
You might want to look into some tutorials on how to work with listviews

Comment: i able to create a script to detect if have word visible false or true, but how to detect the thing on templete gridview?

Comment: try looking into this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207271/enable-and-disable-link-button-on-gridview