# Enable/Disable button on Gridview per row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, buttonclick

I have a `GridView` that has a `Like` and a `Dislike Button` in each `Row`.

What I want to do is for the user to be able to `click` only one of those per `Row` and `Enable` or `Disable` that `Button` per `row` when that particular `Button` is `clicked`.

I have a `Sql Table` `tblVote` that has a `Field` with the `Name Vote`. This Keeps a tally for the user if they have `voted` for that item. If the user `clicks` the `Dislike Button` for the first record it will write a `0` to the `Vote` `Column` under `itemId` `1`. If user `clicks` on `Like` it will write a `1` and so on for each record. I have this part working already. How can I read from the `table` and issue that `Button` that state depending on the `value` on the `Vote Field` on `tblVote`.

```
Table:

ItemId  | UserID  |  Vote

 1      |   123   |   0

 2      |   123   |   1



<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
  GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="SwotItemID" AllowPaging="True"
  AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowCommand="GridViewStrength_RowCommand"
  Width="100%" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
      <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemDesc" HeaderText="Item Description" SortExpression="ItemDesc">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
         </asp:BoundField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Like" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="Vote">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Button ID="Btn_thumbs_up" runat="server" Text = "Like"
                    CommandName="VoteUp" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("SwotItemID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dislike" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="Vote">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Button ID="Btn_thumbs_down" runat="server" Text = "Dislike"
                    CommandName="VoteDown" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("SwotItemID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
         </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
      <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
      <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
      <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
      <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
      <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
      <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
      <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
      <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable and disable link button on gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207271/enable-and-disable-link-button-on-gridview)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do this with a foreach loop. You can do something like..

```
string vote;

//Your connection string. You don't want to open and close within the foreach because it will open and close for each row. Not ideal
conn.Open();

foreach(GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
{
    //you'll want to find the buttons
    Button voteUp = ((Button)gvr.FindControl("Btn_thumbs_up"));
    Button voteDown = ((Button)gvr.FindControl("Btn_thumbs_down"));
    Label SwotItemID = ((Label)gvr.FindControl("SwotItemID));//I would add SwotItemID as a templatefield with an asp label in it in your gridview

    SqlCommand cmdSelectVote= new SqlCommand("SELECT ThumpUpColumn FROM tLoveOrHateTable WHERE SwotItemID = '" + SwotItemID + "'", conn);
    vote = Convert.ToString(cmdSelectVote.ExecuteScalar());


    if(vote == "0")
    {
       voteDown.Enabled = false;
    }
    else if (vote == "1")
    {
       voteUp.Enabled = true;
    }
}
conn.Close();
```

I would have then on page load or a button or something. Whatever populates your data. This is what I would try first then go from there. So what's it is doing it is running that sql statement for each row. If it's a 0, then it disables the thumbs down button. If it is a 1 then it will disable the thumbs up button. It will go row by row, so if you have 1000 rows(I don't imagine that you do) then it could slow things down. Don't hold me that it will work right away as I have not tested it and I wrote it with in the box. Hope this helps!

Comment: should I add this in rowdatabound

Comment: You can try that and see if that works. You can also just put it in it's own method and call that in the page load.